# Does anyone remember how to designate the last cell in a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, shortcuts

There used to be a simple keyboard shortcut to designate the last cell in a spreadsheet.  I've done a lot of searching but everyone keeps saying to highlight, delete, etc.  This is way too much work and it's time-consuming.  Did everyone forget, including me, what short cut this is?  Have they made this more complicated than it needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

No matter where you start from in your worksheet, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will take you to the intersection of the last used column and last used row.

Comment: I know how to find the last cell.  I want the keyboard shortcut to designate what cell is the last cell.

Comment: There are many keyboard shortcuts in this article "[Keyboard shortcuts in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f)", you could have a look. Or maybe this shortcut you are impressed is the shortcut of one macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some data like this:

[image]

And if you want to go to the last cell of a certain row or column, select any cell in that particular row or column and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to go to the last cell in the column and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to go to extreme right or in case if you want to locate the last cell to the left of a cell in the same row, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>. These will help you navigate through a row or column quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have formatting down below your last row of actual data and you use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd> and you find yourself beyond your data. Sometimes even at the very bottom of the sheet.

What you need to do is go to the row after the last row of your data and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>. This will select all the empty cells (that should be empty) below your data.

Then from the **Home** tab, in the **Editing** group. Click the arrow next to **Clear** (the red eraser) and select **Clear all**.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>, save the workbook, close the workbook.

When you open it back up you should be able to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd> and be positioned correctly.